# Mongo DB Memory Utilisation freezes app needs restart

Tags: performance, mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, django

I am running a project using Mongo DB and Django, I have 2 separate instance for my Django project and database each 16GB ram t2xlarge ubuntu ec2 instances.
I am facing issue that within a day or two usage memory on DB server goes above 6GB and on app server it remains below 1GB but freezes application and need to restart machines to recover.
Any suggestions and help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo will always use all free memory, eventually! That's why you don't put application(s) and mongodb to same server. However, you can use [cgroups](http://www.techpaste.com/2016/04/limit-mongodb-memory-usage/) to restrict resource usage (memory, cpu,...) of mongo.

Comment: I am using separate machines for mongo and application..

Comment: So your problem is basically application and not mongo problem. As I wrote, mongo memory usage is normal and expected. Or can you confirm that your mongo freezes and not your application?

Comment: Okay I will check db when next time my application goes down..and then get back to you.. thanks for suggestions.